# I can't login to my azure container registry

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes, azure-container-service, azure-container-registry

I was following the steps in this Microsoft tutorial:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/tutorial-kubernetes-prepare-acr#container-registry-login

I've created a resource group, and then an azure container registry with "az acr create". The next step is to login to the registry, but I keep getting this error:
Error response from daemon: Get https://azurereg.azurecr.io/v2/: Service Unavailable

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please try to use docker login command with username and password? `docker login myregistry.azurecr.io -u xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx -p myPassword`

Comment: @JasonYe-MSFT There is no username and password for it, but even if i enter any credentials, it still responds with the same error, service unavailable.

Comment: Could you please check the resouce status via Azure portal?

Comment: @JasonYe-MSFT It is available. I'm wondering if it might be a proxies (connection) issue?

Comment: Could you please try to use Azure cloud shell to test it?

Comment: @JasonYe I have the same issue... But if use the cloud shell - it works. But why I can not login from my local computer?

Comment: @screamingworld i met the same issue, i restarted my docker application, and then it works.

Answer (score 0):

In order to access ACR from AKS, you can use the underlying service principal. That said, you've to create a role assignment for the Service Principal as mentioned in this paragraph https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-auth-aks?toc=%2fazure%2faks%2ftoc.json#grant-aks-access-to-acr

Creating a role assignment for role `Reader` currently doesn't work. You've to create the assignment for the `Owner` role. (described in https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/76).

Keep in mind that K8s caches the token for a couple of minutes. It took 3-5 minutes on my cluster to work.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error while logging to ACR

Then I use the following command to access the ACR

```
docker login myacrreg.azurecr.io -u myacrreg -p xF1ioa6K4FkKqbtt7j2yPf4rja6tiNvFhT34iq/tUx+ACRCNwSlG
```

you can find this username and password from the following

[image]

To check images (image list in the ACR)

```
docker images myacrreg.azurecr.io
```

Change local image tag with ACR image

```
docker tag myimage12:v1 myacrreg.azurecr.io/myimage12:v1
```

Push into ACR

```
docker push myacrreg.azurecr.io/myimage12:v1
```